# minitoc don't appear in chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, thesis, minitoc, etoc

the minitoc do not appear in the chapters.
Somebody knows where I went wrong?
Here is my preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}% gestion des images
\usepackage{xcolor}% gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{array}% gestion améliorée des tableaux
\usepackage{calc}% syntaxe naurelle pour les calculs
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}% pour les sections
\usepackage{titletoc}% pour la table des matières
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour les en-têtes
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{supertabular} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{times} % La police

\newenvironment{Changement_De_Police}
{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}{}

\usepackage{titling}% pour le titre
\usepackage{enumitem}% pour les listes numérotées
\usepackage{hyperref}% gestion des hyperliens
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=XYZ}% zoom par défaut
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}

\renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{XXXX, YYYYY, ZZZZZ}}

\fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{ AAA \;\;\;BBB: 2020-2021\;\;\;\;CCC}}

\rfoot{\thepage}

\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}

\fancyhead[L]{}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \include{Preface/Page_de_garde_main}
 \include{Preface/Dédicaces}
 \include{Preface/Citattion}
 \include{Preface/Remerciements_main}
 \include{Preface/Resumé_main}
 \include{Preface/abstract_main}
 \tableofcontents 
 \listoftables
 %\addstarredchapter{LISTE DES TABLEAUX}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LISTE DES TABLEAUX}
 \listoffigures%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LISTE DES FIGURES}
 %\addstarredchapter{LISTE DES FIGURES}
 \pdfbookmark[1]{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{table}
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \include{Corps/Introduction_Conclusion/introduction_main}
 \include{Corps/Pres/Pres_main}
 \include{Corps/Chap1/Chap1_main}
 \include{Corps/Chap2/Chap2_main}
 \include{Corps/Chap4/Chap4_main}
 \include{Corps/Chap5/Chap5_main}
 \include{Corps/Introduction_Conclusion/Conclusion_main}
 \include {Corps/Bibliographie/Bibli_main}
 \include{Corps/Annxes/Annexes_main}
 
\end{document}
```

In the chapters there is this :

```
\chapter{Blablabla}
\minitoc
\section{ ok ok ok}
\subsection{ ok2 ok2 ok2}
```

For the quotes

```
\chapter*{CITATION}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CITATION}
\begin{Changement_De_Police}
{\LARGE 
" L'observation est mère du raisonnement"
}
\end{Changement_De_Police}
```

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1** You will save a lot of time using `etoc`. It takes all the information it needs from the `.toc` file so it doesn't need any more compilations.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
%%%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}% gestion des images
\usepackage{xcolor}% gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{array}% gestion améliorée des tableaux
\usepackage{calc}% syntaxe naurelle pour les calculs
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}% pour les sections
%%\usepackage{titletoc}% pour la table des matières
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour les en-têtes
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{supertabular} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{times} % La police

\newenvironment{Changement_De_Police}
{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}{}

\usepackage{titling}% pour le titre
\usepackage{enumitem}% pour les listes numérotées

\usepackage{etoc} % added
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{hyperref}% gestion des hyperliens LAST PACKAGE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=XYZ}% zoom par défaut

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{XXXX, YYYYY, ZZZZZ}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{ AAA \;\;\;BBB: 2020-2021\;\;\;\;CCC}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{} 

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
        
    \frontmatter    % roman numbering   
    \chapter*{Preface}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface} 
    1. \kant[1]
        
    \tableofcontents
                
    \etocsettocstyle{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.3\baselineskip\sffamily}%
    {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.5\baselineskip} % etoc style for locals TOC 
    
    \mainmatter % arabic numbering
    \chapter{Chap 1}  
    \localtableofcontents
    1. \kant[1]
    \section{C1 S1} 
    2. \kant[11]    
    \section{C1 S2} 
    3. \kant[3]     
    \section{C1 S3} 
    4. \kant[14] 
    
    \chapter{Chap 2}
    \localtableofcontents   
    \section{C2 S1} 
    9. \kant[9]
    \section{C2 S2}
    10. \kant[10]
    \subsection{C2 S2 Sub1}
    11. \kant[11]
    
    \chapter*{CITATION}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CITATION}
    \begin{Changement_De_Police}
        {\LARGE 
            " L'observation est mère du raisonnement"
        }
    \end{Changement_De_Police}
\end{document}
```

**OPTION 2** Using `minitoc` (use `\dominitoc` before `\chapter*{...}`)

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
%%%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}% gestion des images
\usepackage{xcolor}% gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{array}% gestion améliorée des tableaux
\usepackage{calc}% syntaxe naurelle pour les calculs
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}% pour les sections
%%\usepackage{titletoc}% pour la table des matières
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour les en-têtes
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{supertabular} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{times} % La police

\newenvironment{Changement_De_Police}
{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}{}

\usepackage{titling}% pour le titre
\usepackage{enumitem}% pour les listes numérotées

\usepackage{minitoc}
\mtcselectlanguage{french}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{hyperref}% gestion des hyperliens LAST PACKAGE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=XYZ}% zoom par défaut

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{XXXX, YYYYY, ZZZZZ}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{ AAA \;\;\;BBB: 2020-2021\;\;\;\;CCC}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{}

\begin{document}
    
\frontmatter    % roman numbering
\dominitoc
\chapter*{Preface}
\addstarredchapter{Preface}
1. \kant[1]

\tableofcontents    
\listoffigures
\listoftables 

\mainmatter % arabic numbering
\chapter{Chap 1}  
\minitoc
1. \kant[1]
\section{C1 S1} 
2. \kant[11]    
\section{C1 S2} 
3. \kant[3]     
\section{C1 S3} 
4. \kant[14] 

\chapter{Chap 2}
\minitoc
\section{C2 S1} 
9. \kant[9]
\section{C2 S2}
10. \kant[10]
\subsection{C2 S2 Sub1}
11. \kant[11]

\chapter*{CITATION}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CITATION}
\begin{Changement_De_Police}
{\LARGE 
" L'observation est mère du raisonnement"
}
\end{Changement_De_Police}

\end{document}
```